# single cert for two alias name

Tags: linux, apache, ssl

is it possible to use single certificate in `apache` for two alias domain name using some kind of redirect using URL rewrite etc? like following. I want to redirect example.com to `www.example.com`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Problem is i have SSL certificate registered for `www.example.com` domain and i have CNAME example.com but i am getting SSL warning on example.com, can i use above trick to make it work?

Comment: Do you have a certificate for both domains?

Comment: No, I have only for www.example.com

Comment: In this case you need to buy another certificate. Some time ago it was possible to redirect in plain unencrypted http, but this is not supported today.

Comment: I don't have money to buy two certificate thats why i am looking for redirect or something like that.. to use one cert for two name

Comment: You could buy a wildcard certificate that would slove your problem. By the way I payed about 50 USD for my wildcard certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a certificate valid for multiple host names when it has multiple Subject Alternative Names or when it's a wildcard certificate (or both).

Wildcard certificates are not particularly useful for `www.example.com` and `example.com` because the dot isn't part of the pattern, so `*.example.com` wouldn't match `example.com`. Such a wildcard certificate would need an additional SAN for `example.com` anyway in this case.

CAs have various commercial names for certificates with multiple SANs, and often charge extra for then.

However, the `www` is considered by many a special case. Some CAs will issue a cert with SANs for `www.example.com` and `example.com` when you apply for `www.example.com`, without an extra fee.

You could also use two distinct certificates but, unless you know all your clients support Server Name Indication (SNI), you would need a separate IP address for each.

Comment: Technically, yes, in the sense that they'll need 2 SAN entries, but practically, some CAs consider this part of their single domain offer (with and without the `www.` prefix).

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons every certificate is limited to a domain. Some certificates are fore a hole bunch of domains like wildcard certificates, such a certificate would slove your problem, but in commem they cost double or trippel of the normal price.

Another way would be a certificate for two domains but this is not very simple to configure. However this certificate needs to be signed by a certificate authority.

So now you cannot do anything except to buy another certificate.

I almost forgot it, you can get free certificates from https://startssl.com/. Not with your name but for a redirect it should be fine.